# Como obtener id y opcion seleccionada de Select de una clase

Tags: jquery

Tengo un DataTable en un formulario de cheques..Para cada cheque tengo un select de acciones:

```
     {  title:"ACCION",
          
            className: "center",
            "render": function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
            return `<select class="ACCION" id=${row.idcheque}><option 
    value="0">SELECCIONE</option><option value="1">ENTREGADO</option><option 
     value="2">COBRADO</option><option value="3">FACTURADO</option></select>`;
     
            }
        }
```

Entonces hago:

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      listar();
        $(".ACCION").on("click",function(){
        var idcheque=$(this).attr("id");
        var opcion=$(this).val();
        alert(idcheque);
 });
});
```

Pero no me toma el evento.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando quieres seleccionar un elemento que se ha generado de manera dinámica, no vas a poder llamando a su clase o ID directamente. Tienes que hacerlo mediente  algun elemento creado de manera estática, por ejemplo: `$(document)`.

Prueba a utilizar algo asi:

```
$(document).on('click','.ACCION', function() {
    //tu código
})
```

Comment: Gracias..Funciono a la perfeccion.